# Python Pandas: Drop rows from data frame if list of string value == [none]

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

I have a column in my data frame that contains lists of values.

```
 Tags
 [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
 [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
 [none]
 [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
 [today, show, today, show, today]
 [none]
 [mark, wahlberg, marky, mark]
```

I don't know how to remove this [none] list from the data frame. I tried,

```
 us_videos = us_videos.drop(us_videos.index[us_videos.tags == 'none'])
```

But this only working when I turn the column into string. How to achieve this?

Comment: Try: `us_videos[us_videos.tags.map(['none'].__ne__)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New Answer

OP wanted to remove `'none'` from sub-lists and remove rows with only `'none'`

```
us_videos.tags.explode().pipe(lambda s: s[s != 'none']).groupby(level=0).agg(list)

0        [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1          [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
3    [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
4            [today, show, today, show, today]
6                [mark, wahlberg, marky, mark]
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

A more pythonic way

```
dat = {}
for k, v in us_videos.tags.iteritems():
    for x in v:
        if x != 'none':
            dat.setdefault(k, []).append(x)

pd.Series(dat, name='tags')

0        [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1          [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
3    [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
4            [today, show, today, show, today]
6                [mark, wahlberg, marky, mark]
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

With assignment expressions in a comprehension

```
pd.Series({
    k: X for k, v in us_videos.tags.iteritems()
    if (X:=[*filter('none'.__ne__, v)])
}, name='tags')

0        [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1          [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
3    [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
4            [today, show, today, show, today]
6                [mark, wahlberg, marky, mark]
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

---

## OLD ANSWERS

#### `explode`

```
us_videos[us_videos.tags.explode().ne('none').any(level=0)]

                                        tags
0      [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1        [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
3  [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
4          [today, show, today, show, today]
6              [mark, wahlberg, marky, mark]
```

---

#### `list.__ne__`

```
us_videos[us_videos.tags.map(['none'].__ne__)]

                                        tags
0      [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1        [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
3  [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
4          [today, show, today, show, today]
6              [mark, wahlberg, marky, mark]
```

Comment: This is working great! This is only deleting the [none] from the column not the none inside the list,  [today, show, today, show, today, none], right?

Comment: That is correct... now it's correct. I changed `all` to `any`

Comment: This doesn't remove `'none'` from the list. It simply returns back the same list which contains `'none'` values in the list. it works on the lists that `'none'` is the only element. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong.  I may have misunderstood what you needed.  If you want to remove the `'none'` from the list **AND** remove the rows that contain only `'none'`... one sec

Answer (score 2):

First let's write a function to get rid of `'none'` in the lists:

```
print(df)

    tags
0   [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1   [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
2   [none]
3   [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt, times]
4   [today, show, today, show, today, none]


def delete_none(element):
    new = []
    for val in element:
        if val != 'none':
            new.append(val)
    if len(new) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return new
```

Now we apply this function on `tags` column:

```
df.tags.apply(delete_none)
```

Output:

```
0         [marvel, comics, comic, books, nerdy]
1           [new, snapchat, version, snap, inc]
2                                           NaN
3    [new, york, times, ny, times, nyt,  times]
4             [today, show, today, show, today]
```

Comment: It didn't work. 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'.

Comment: It is working thank you! This deletes every none in the list even if it was between the list such as  [today, show, today, show, today, none], right? What if I just want to delete the single [none]?

Comment: Ohh! that is different. I thought you want to get rid of that row completely. I'll update my answer.

Comment: From this we could remove NaN values from the data frame. Thank you so much!

Comment: I created a new dataframe that has `none` between the list elements, and wrote a function to return `np.nan` if list has only `none`, otherwise it deletes `none` from the list. let me know how it works.

Comment: Exactly, you can easily do a boolean mask selection on the dataframe. Good luck!